# Cleaning metrics in Prometheus after recording rules computation

Tags: prometheus

I have a federate job in Prometheus that scrape metrics (requests number) from several machines.

The problem is that those metrics come with a wide range of label combinations (like IP address, container metadata, etc) so I've added a recording rule that does the sum of all the incoming metrics and save it in a new metric with only the labels I need. As a result, I only have ~10 combinations of labels instead of 200k.

**Question**: Is there a way to remove the original metrics but not the one that comes from the recording rule?

Possible solutions:

- `--storage.tsdb.retention.time` but this will delete everything (both original and computed metrics)
- `POST to api/v1/admin/tsdb/delete_series` but I was looking for something more *elegant*. Also, if I delete an entire series, what will happen with the recording rule that didn't have the time to compute yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do what you want within a single Prometheus instance short of deleting the time series you are no longer interested in. BTW, `/api/v1/admin/tsdb/series` [apparently accepts](https://www.robustperception.io/deleting-time-series-from-prometheus) `start` and `end` parameters, allowing you to e.g. only delete the original time series' older samples.

The other alternative is to have one Prometheus instance do the scraping and aggregation (as you do now) with a very short retention time. And have a second Prometheus instance with a long retention time scrape the first one for the aggregation results (and whatever other metrics you want to keep). This is called ["federation"](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).

Comment: Both are good options. I've missed the start/end parameters in the API so I think I will go with this one